# Setting function interval on multiple targets, clearing interval after some delay

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm developing an effect where symbols would change when user hovers on them.

I've achieved part of it - elements change on hover as they should. What I can not manage to achieve is for symbols to keep changing for few seconds after element is not hovered anymore and only then stop instead of stopping immediately.

Full fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wehvm457/3/

Javascript:

```
var
   target = $(".symbol").find('span'),
   possible = ['?', '/', '<', '>', '}', '{', ')', '(', '[', '[', '!', '2', '3', '1', '4', '5', '6', '7', '&', '$', '#'];

var  pickRandom  = function(element) {
        random = Math.floor(Math.random()*possible.length);
        symbol = possible[random];
        currentTarget.html(symbol);
      }

$(target).on({
mouseenter: function () {
  currentTarget = $(this);
  changeSymbols = setInterval(pickRandom, 100);
},

mouseleave: function () {
  // currentTarget = $(this);
  // setTimeout(function(){
    clearInterval(changeSymbols);
  // }, 1000)
}
```

});

Would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be able to store instance specific references to `setInterval` instead of using the global `changeSymbols`. You can do this by storing each reference on the element itself using `data()`

Similarly the `currentTarget` won't work when you have multiple instances running so need to use the `element` argument of `pickRandom` instead and call that function passing in the element

```
var pickRandom = function($el) {
  random = Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length);
  symbol = possible[random];
  $el.html(symbol);
}

$(target).on({
  mouseenter: function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
      pickRandom($el)
    }, 100);

    $el.data('timer', timer)
  },

  mouseleave: function() {
    var timer = $(this).data('timer')
    setTimeout(function() {
      clearInterval(timer);
    }, 1000)
  }
});
```

[Updated Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wehvm457/4/)

Comment: Thank you a lot, sir or madam!

Comment: The only problem I see is if you enter the element again before the `setTimeout` occurs in which case you may also need to `clearInterval` in `mouseenter` also